# How do I format a single raid 5 hard drive?

Tags: raid, raid-5, windows-10, storage-spaces

**I'd like to know how to format a single former raid 5 hard drive**

If I boot up without the other raid 5 drives then Windows doesn't see it; it doesn't appear in Disk Management, or whilst booted into the Windows installation in DOS.

*See below for more information on the set up I'm currently running.*

I have a [HP Proliant N40L Microserver](http://n40l.wikia.com/wiki/HP_MicroServer_N40L_Wiki) running a raid 5 using Windows 10 Storage Spaces. There are a total of 4 hard drives in the microserver:

- 750gb (Windows 10)
- 3 x 2tb Western Digital Green

A few days after I set up a raid Windows 10 Storage Spaces flagged one of the hard drives as 'Retired' (unusable). The three Western Digital Green hard drives are brand new. However I replaced the hard drive causing the issue with a new one of exactly the same spec.

The raid rebuilt itself but after a day Windows 10 Storage Spaces flagged it as 'Retired'.

I'm not sure what's causing this issue. All the hard drives on the raid are new, and with the issue happening on a drive I only just replaced, I'm reluctant to blame the hard drives. Most of the components within the Microserver are new - apart from the Microserver itself.

I'd like to format the hard drive and attempt to rebuild the raid again, but Windows does not recognise the drive. If anyone has any advise I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: What you expect from us? Remote hardware debugging? Because the way it looks like now is that something is bad with the drives. Which could be a faulty port, bad SATA cable etc. You are right to be reluctant to blame the drive (after the replacement). But we have not enough information to do diagnose remotely.It could be something wrong with green drives (hanging on startup too long for storage spaces) or.... it is something hardware drive related. Put the drive on another port with another sata cable, for a start.

Comment: What do the SMART stats for the disks in the Array say about their mechanical health? are you seeing reallocated sectors or a high raw read error rate?

Comment: To be fair I'm only asking how to format a former raid 5 hard drive. The rest of the information is there to provide context, and on the off chance that someone else has experienced a similar issue with raid 5 using Windows Storage Spaces.

Comment: In general the RAID controller must perform the formatting, so it should be as simple as taking the drive out, formatting it as somthing, and putting it back in the array to be reinitialized. Not sure what marking the disk as Retired entails and whether the status "sticks" across formats. you may want to look here: https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/3xdojw/windows_10_storage_space_drives_marked_as_retired/

Comment: So the "retired" drive is gone from `Disk Management` and `Device Manager`?